p-dropdown Stopped Working After Upgrading From primeng 9 to primeng 10
I have a 3 p-dropdown components that are shown or hidden based on what tab the user is on in a modal. When the component loads, 3 api calls are made to the 3 endpoints that supply the entries for the 3 dropdowns and those objects are stored in 3 lists. The html looks like this:
<p-dropdown
     *ngIf="activeTabIndex === 0"
     [style]="{'z-index': '9999', 'width': '430px'}"
     name="skillId"
     id="skillId"
     placeholder="Skill Requirement"
     [filter]="true"
     optionLabel="label"
     [options]="skillsVocab"
     [(ngModel)]="selectedCapability"
></p-dropdown>
...two more dropdowns with activeTabIndex 1 and 2...

I know the api calls and the tab index variable is working, because I put in console logs that are showing the expected outputs of 0 and a list of objects that populate the dropdown. I have other dropdowns in the project that still work just fine and are set up similarly, the main difference here is the use of ngIf. This dropdown worked just fine in primeng 9 and didn't start having an issue until the upgrade to 10, but I don't see anything in the 10 changelog that would indicate the need to change how the options are written. When clicking the dropdown, the component flashes for a single frame like it's trying to load but nothing appears. There are no errors in the console.
EDIT: After adding and removing stuff a couple more times, I discovered that removing [filter]="true" fixed it. I'm not sure what primeng is doing in the background that breaks in this specific instance because I am using filters in dropdowns in other locations in the web app, but I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the dropdown is in a tree table and that doesn't play nice for whatever reason. The dropdown is cut off by the bottom of the cell in the table and appendTo="body" just makes it not appear (probably hidden behind the modal? idk), but that issue is unrelated to the original problem.
